# Test capybara devise sign in with subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, capybara

I want to test sign in process. In my app each user has it's own subdomain. And when I try to test sign in process it allways writes error that password or email is invalid.

Here is test code

```
scenario do
  user = create(:confirmed_user)
  Capybara.app_host = "http://#{user.subdomain}.lvh.me"
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email
  fill_in 'user_password', with: "Passw0rd"
  click_link_or_button "Sign in"
end
```

Login and password are 100% correct.
Also I've tried to do everything that written in this article
http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/
but it didn't help. Also, test for login of admin user without subdomain works perfectly.

Maybe I miss something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you are testing a remote server? or how are you handling the domain lookup?

Comment: No, not remote server. lvh.me is the same as localhost, but it makes using subdomains possible.

Comment: try to configure capybara to always use the port https://gist.github.com/turadg/5399790